# Android: Apparent memory leak when sending lots of messages through a Handler

Tags: android, callback, handler, memory-leaks, sendmessage

I've got an app where a thread is trying to send lots of Location objects via a Handler to the UI thread, where they get analyzed and passed on to other threads.  I've noticed the app has a memory leak, as it eventually crashes 2-3 hours after starting up.  If I use DDMS to profile the heap, I notice a gradual increase in the number of "Data Objects" (about 1500 per minute).  It appears those 1500 are approximately evenly split between 16-byte and 32-byte items.

After gradually disabling parts of my app, I found that the Location generating thread's call to the Handler appears to cause the leak.

I have gradually narrowed down the required parts of my thread to this:

```
class UIActivity implements Handler.Callback
{
@Override 
public void onCreate()
{
  m_handler = new Handler(this);
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message m)
{
  switch(m.what)
  { 
    case FAKE_LOCATION:
      m.obj = null; // desperate anti-leak measures
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
public static class FakeLocationGenerator extends Thread
{
  private Handler m_callback;
  public FakeLocationGenerator(Handler callback)
  {
    m_callback = callback;
    start();
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    while(true)
    {
      Thread.sleep(50); // makes for 20hz
      Location l = new Location("fake");
      Message m = new Message();
      m.what = FAKE_LOCATION;
      m.obj = l;
      m_callback.SendMessage(m);
    }
  }
}
}
```

The Handler.Callback.handleMessage() implementation on the UI activity just returns true and does nothing with the message.  If I comment out the m_callback.SendMessage call, then the memory leak disappears.  I tried a giant hack of calling Handler.removeMessages(FAKE_LOCATION) after each FAKE_LOCATION message, but that did nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should be using Message.obtain() and Message.recycle().

Secondly, is it possible that maybe there is no leak and you are simply generating new messages faster than they are being processed...?

Comment: Ah, that may help.  When should I call recycle() in that case?  One other question I read while researching my problem indicated recycle() automatically gets called after handleMessage(), and said I shouldn't be calling it.

I don't think I'm generating them too fast (as the stripped-down handleMessage() currently does nothing), but I'll check tonight to see if there's a 1:1 handleMessage() vs sendMessage() call ratio.

Here's the link I found on recycle(): http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f691ee73b946ba76?pli=1

Comment: This appears to have helped greatly.  I'm still leaking through various means, but it isn't through the Handler anymore.

Comment: @ArtHare So, should we call message.recycle?

Comment: @KimiChiu My memory isn't great, but it appears that I "upped" the answer, so I think recycle() was the answer.